# Show Content from other websites using RSS in my Drupal Site

Tags: drupal-6

I would like to show content from other websites using RSS Feeds into my drupal site and show it inside a page.

I searched for RSS. There are so many. Can you suggest a good one?

I'm trying to show the content from here
http://feeds.feedburner.com/brazen_careerist

Update: i tried installing the feeds module and i gave this url 
http://feeds.feedburner.com/brazen_careerist?format=xml

it imported all the items. How do i auto-import only the latest ones and auto-format it and make it available on my site whenever it's available from the source

Thanks a lot

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

To have it setup to auto import you have to play around with the "Importers basic settings". Checkout the handbook page for Feeds [here](http://drupal.org/node/622698)

> Go to "Basic settings". Decide whether
>   the importer should be used on a
>   standalone form or by creating a node
>   ("Attached to content type"); decide
>   whether the importer should
>   periodically refresh the feed and in
>   what time interval it should do that
>   ("Minimum refresh period").

I'm not quite sure what you mean by auto-format but I think you might want to look at field mapping (information is on the handbook page as well).

Hope it helps.